# Webservice Report Export ReportExecution2005.asmx 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to connect to a SSRS Server 2008 r2 to access the webservice.

```
 http://srsserver/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx
```

But whenever I tried to connect to the URL I get a 404 error. I have logged onto the server

the file exists of the file server in program files\Microsoft SQL Server\servername\Reporting Services\ReportServer

I am not sure how to troubleshoot the 404 issue any ideas ?

Comment: ah I needed to use ReportService2010.asmx

Comment: Yea, 2005 still works for most. If you upgrade to MSSQL2012 you may need to upgrade to make use of new features.

Comment: Are you setting user credentials this scenario?

Comment: ReportExecution2005 and ReportService2010 are two distinct endpoints, you should be able to access the former one as well, since both are available in SSRS2008R2. Remember that you have to give a port number when you try to access the endpoint, e.g. h ttp://srsserver:80/...